# What UI lib or something can i use to simulate traffic conditions with moving stuff with C++?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, user-interface

Our Object-oriented technology curriculum's homework:

using object-oriented language to implement a application simulating traffic condition, with following requirements:

1. Must have UI to simulate traffic scenaria (moving cars, changing traffic lights etc.).
2. There are traffic lights at the intersections
3. Car have limited turning options when encounting traffic lights at intersections

I want to use C++ to implement this application, but i never have had experience coding for user interface. how to program with c++ to implement something that can make some dynamic illustration to show my application? can Qt satisfy my requirements? if not what lib can i use?

Comment: Essentially any of the usual suspects (E.g., Qt, wxWidgets, GTK+, even MFC) *can* do what you've described. It's strictly a matter of choosing the one you want to use (but Qt is probably one of the better choices).

Comment: You don't use a GUI library to simulate things, you use it to display things and take user input. Just sayin'.

Comment: Have a look at Qt's QGraphicsView, that should be a good match for your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick start for you:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-collidingmice.html

Study the example and figure out what is going on.

Change the mice into cars.  Create boundary conditions for how they navigate.  Maybe swap the subclass to a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, or a `QGraphicsRectItem`.

Change what they do as they approach or intersect with another car.

Then when you are ready, add in traffic light representation, and have the cars detect the upcoming traffic light.

Instead of just detecting collisions at the time of drawing, you can have a QTimer event that recalculates the "driving decision" of the car based on the nearby cars and what they were doing.

Use `QPropertyAnimations`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/animation-animatedtiles.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: really thank you for your helpful answer, it means a lot to a novice like to to complete this task, i think i kown how to get start. Can i send email to you for help when i encount barriers.